# How can one increase the resolution of a video in BlueJeans?

Tags: windows, video-streaming, bluejeans

How can one increase the resolution of a video in BlueJeans (either from the person who shares the video or the person who receives it)?

For example, with https://meet.google.com, I can [adjust the video quality in Settings -> Network](https://support.google.com/meet/answer/7294914?hl=en).

I use BlueJeans on Microsoft Windows.

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: I am still interested if someone has any idea.